# Wget downloading github tar.gz file as html document , UTF-8 Unicode text?

Tags: linux, tar, wget, html

I need to download this file :
https://github.com/cbherer/Bherer_etal_SexualDimorphismRecombination/blob/master/Refined_genetic_map_b37.tar.gz

Here is my command:

```
wget https://github.com/cbherer/Bherer_etal_SexualDimorphismRecombination/blob/master/Refined_genetic_map_b37.tar.gz
```

The file was downloaded, but I want to reach the text files in it. I tried :

```
tar -zxvf Refined_genetic_map_b37.tar.gz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I checked the file :

```
file Refined_genetic_map_b37.tar.gz
Refined_genetic_map_b37.tar.gz: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

So, what should I do to extract the text files of it ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong URL to access the file.  What you are fetching is a web page.  The correct URL is

```
https://github.com/cbherer/Bherer_etal_SexualDimorphismRecombination/raw/master/Refined_EUR_genetic_map_b37.tar.gz
```

Notice `raw` instead of `blob`.

You would see this URL if you went to you original URL and checked the link connected to the "Download" button on the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works !

Answer (score 0):

As pointed [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda), you need to download the `raw` , here is another link (it can be downloaded also through the browser):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cbherer/Bherer_etal_SexualDimorphismRecombination/master/Refined_genetic_map_b37.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works !